# Force Bootstrap to use specific JQuery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have situation when I have 2 JQuery version on the page with `newJQ=Jquery.noConflict(true)` in use.

The versions are: 1.8.2 and 3.1.1

When I load Bootstrap 3 from cdn it uses 1.8.2 version, that is understandable but it throws me error that it is required 1.9.1 min jquery version.
Is there is a way to tell to loaded bootstrap to use newJQ and not old one

Comment: What order are you loading your scripts in?

Comment: @DNKROZ 1.8.2>3.1.1>bootstrap - and I have no way to change this order

Comment: Why can't you change the order? I'd say load 3.1.1>bootstrap>jQuery.noConflict>1.8.2

Comment: @DNKROZ System constraints :((((

Comment: I know you have a situation to use 2 `jQuery` version, but try keeping only one i.e. `jQuery 3.1.1` and keep it before `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: Using 2 versions you're probably going to need to change the order I'm afraid.. unless you can make it work with 1 as suggested by @Shiladitya